# Find the limit of $\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}\sin^2(2^{j-1}\pi f)\prod_{i=0}^{j-2} \cos^2(2^i\pi f)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometric-series

Can anyone give a hint on how to see if the following has a limit? $f$ stands for frequency.

$$\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}\sin^2(2^{j-1}\pi f)\prod_{i=0}^{j-2} \cos^2(2^i\pi f)$$

I've tried a few different things, but nothing seems to be working. Any help?

Comment: for what stands the variable $f$ here?

Comment: You wrote $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$, but there is no $\text{“}n\text{''}$ in the expression that follows that. Might you have intended $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}$ instead? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: What is $n$? $j$?  Or something else?

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: What are the few things that you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since $\sin (2x)=2\sin x\cos x$ we have $$\cos x =\frac{\sin (2x)}{\sin x}\qquad\text{for }\sin x \neq 0$$
then, if $\;2^if\notin \mathbb{Z}$ for every $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, $$\prod_{i=0}^{j-2} \cos^2(2^i\pi f)=\prod_{i=0}^{j-2} \frac{\sin^2(2^{i+1}\pi f)}{\sin^2 (2^i\pi f)}=\frac{\sin^2(2^{j-1}\pi f)}{\sin^2(\pi f)}$$